# How does one show that the function $f(x,y) = \frac{x-y}{x+y}$ is discontinuous along the line $y=-x$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How does one show that the function 
$ f(x,y) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \frac{x-y}{x + y} & \quad \text{if (x,y) $\neq$ (x,-x)}\\
    1 & \quad \text{if (x,y) = (x,-x)}
  \end{array} \right.$

is discontinuous along the line $y=-x$? Is it sufficient to show that the limit of the function would be infinity as $y$ approaches $-x$? I'm having issues figuring out how to write this since it is not a simple point.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask if a function is continuous at points where it isn't defined. Most calculus books say it's automatically discontinuous at points that aren't in the domain. I personally do not like that, but that's life.

Comment: Completely left that part out, my apologies.

Comment: Ah. Well, the limit isn't infinity, but you can for sure show it isn't $1$.

Comment: Well what would it be? I guess I'm having trouble with that then.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin not necessarily, some functions aren't defined at certain values yet can be made continuous by an appropriate correction, e.g. $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$.

Comment: @AlexSiryj, that is a totally different question. BridgeSkier, the limit does not exist. $|f(x,y)|\to\infty$.

Comment: @TedShifrin : The alternative is to disregard points outside the domain (with regards to questions of continuity).  Then "$1/x$ is continuous".  Rogawski's Calculus with Early Transcendentals does this.  This leads to the awkwardness that "continuous functions are integrable" and "$1/x$ is continuous" doesn't mean $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x$ exists.

Comment: @EricTowers, one needs to say that a continuous function on a closed interval is integrable. I'm totally in that camp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the value of the function along the line $y = x$?

> That would be $0/2$ except at $(0,0)$, where it's $1$.

What's the value of the function along the line $y = mx + b$?

> That would be $\dfrac{x - (mx+b)}{x + (mx+b)} = \dfrac{(1-m)x + b}{(1+m)x + b}$.  As $x$ approaches $\dfrac{-b}{m+1}$ this diverges to $\pm\infty$ (depending on which side you're approaching from), but then has the value $1$ at $x = \dfrac{-b}{m+1}$.

Are these continuous where they intersect the line $y = -x$?

> For the first, that's at the point taking the value $1$, so it is not continuous where it meets the line $y = -x$.
>
> For the second, that's where $-x = mx +b$, or at $x = \dfrac{-b}{m+1}$, the discontinuity.
>  
>  So the function certainly has discontinuities along the line $y = -x$.  It's not so hard to show that it is continuous off the line.  (It is the ratio of polynomials where the denominator is nonzero.)